# Как создать метод, принимающий любой Enum в Java?

Tags: java, enum

Имеется несколько `Enum`:

```java
public enum Colours {
    RED, BLUE, WHITE;
}

public enum Modification {
    FULL, SIMPLE;
}
```

Как создать метод, который в качестве аргумента будет принимать любой типа перечисления (или `TypeColour` или `Modification` ) и возвращать значение, тип которого равен типу аргумента? Имеется множество перечислений и хочется сделать один универсальный метод:

```java
Modification mod = getAnyEnum(Modification, "SIMPLE");
// mod = Modification.SIMPLE;

или

Colours col = getAnyEnum(Colours , "RED");
// mod = Modification.SIMPLE;
```

Чтобы получилось что-то типа такого:

```java
private <E extends Enum<E>> E getAnyEnum(E type, String tagName) {
   //сделать что-то типа
   E newType = E.values(); //или метод valueOf();
   
   for(E type: list) {
       if(type.getValue.equals(tagName)) {
           return type;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: а не сериализация  ли имеется ввиду? а-ля "xml to enum" или "json to enum"

Comment: @kami, это я хочу использовать при парсинге `XML-документа`. Метод будет принимать имя тега XML-документа и создавать соответствующий `Enum`.

Comment: использовать JAXB и настроить маппинг полей - не рассматриваете? например - так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38638235/4908529

Comment: @kami, возьму на заметку, но сейчас нужно обойтись без `jaxb`.

Comment: так тоже возможно. Русскоязычный вариант, увы, не нагуглился: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1723239/4908529  . Но вы можете создать его! :)

Comment: @kami, вроде рабочий код, опубликуйте в качестве ответа, я приму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это - перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/1723239/4908529

Обратите внимание на комментарии: основные претензии - к пустому catch-блоку, что считается моветоном. Публикуемый метод возвращает NULL, если значение, соответствующее строковому представлению не найдено.

```java
/**
 * A common method for all enums since they can't have another base class
 * @param <T> Enum type
 * @param c enum type. All enums must be all caps.
 * @param string case insensitive
 * @return corresponding enum, or null
 */
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T getEnumFromString(Class<T> c, String string) {
    if( c != null && string != null ) {
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(c, string.trim().toUpperCase());
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Пример использования:

```java
public static MyEnum fromString(String name) {
    return getEnumFromString(MyEnum.class, name);
}
```

Если значения вашего Enum использует не только заглавные буквы - нужно будет изменить часть кода `string.trim().toUpperCase()` на более подходящую для вашей нотации.